# Mangling a url in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am mangling a url with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATAFACTORIES="$(az resource list --resource-group XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --resource-type Microsoft.DataFactory/factories --query [*].id -otsv)"
for df in $DATAFACTORIES; do
    my_uri=https://management.azure.com$df/?api-version=2018-06-01
    TRIGGERS="$(az rest --method GET --uri $my_uri)"
done
```

The command that is being run is:

```
az rest --method GET --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YYYY/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Micros/?api-version=2018-06-01s/zzz
```

when I expect it to be:

```
az rest --method GET --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YYYY/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/zzz?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because `az` returned result with DOS line endings, try :

```
my_uri="https://management.azure.com${df%$'\r'}/?api-version=2018-06-01"
```

`${df%$'\r'}` removes `\r` from the end of the variable `df`